# MS Graph API GraphServiceException Error Handling In Java

Tags: error-handling, microsoft-graph-api

I understand that you throw GraphServiceException when an error occurs in the MS Graph API. So I handled the error as follows.

```java
try {
    // MS Graph API
} catch (GraphServiceException e) {
    if (e.getServiceError().isError(GraphErrorCodes.AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_DENIED)) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Debugging the e.getServiceError() value shows:

[image]

But the result of the above if statement is false. In addition to this, I always get false if I compare other exception codes with GraphErrorCodes as above, is my method wrong?

What is best way for error handling of MS Graph?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Best of way handling the expected errors:

[image]

To Resolve Microsoft Graph authorization errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors

Hope this helps.